# Iterate through list of files & run script

Tags: python, export, import, loop

I created a script that runs on an individual file, but I want to automate it to run on a long list of files. Essentially, I want to automate this:

1. Import file from list
2. Various script steps
3. Export to new file
4. Clear current scene/model/data/objects/etc (presumably through opening the startup .blend file which I have removed all items from)
5. Loop to next file on list

Import/export instead of open/save because file is in a non-native blender format.

Any direction would be appreciated, as I am still relatively new to Blender and Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that should work. I assume you want to import gltf but you can swap the importer and extension quite easily.

```
from pathlib import Path
import bpy

model_filepaths = [f for f in Path(r"D:\path\to\your\folder").glob('**/*.gltf') if f.is_file()]

for filepath in model_filepaths:
    # Create a brand new file
    bpy.ops.wm.read_homefile()
    # Import model
    bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf(filepath=str(filepath))
    # Do something
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        print(obj.name)
    # Save file
    bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=str(filepath.with_suffix(".blend")))
```

Comment: In testing out bpy.ops.wm.read_homefile, it causes the import to fail and errors out. Snippet of error message:
    if bpy.context.object and bpy.context.object.type == 'ARMATURE':
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'object'

Comment: Please post your script, these lines are not part of my answer

Comment: Just added the test code in my post above. The issue looks to be that bpy.ops.wm.read_homefile() clears context to None (for example, bpy.context.window, etc.)

Comment: Yup, I suggest adding a small delay with an application timer so the context initializes. https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html You can also try purging everything in the file instead of loading a brand new one but there might be leftover data and it will take more time